# How to send multiple form parameters in request?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, request, python-requests

Iam working on a project where multiple form parameters need to be specified of which one is file itself.

**What i tried:**

```
import requests
REST_URL = 'http://192.168.150.138:8888/tasks/create/file'
with open(os.path.join('/home/default/Batch/Samples/', filename),'rb') as sample:
          files = {'file'  :("temp_file_name" , sample)}
          r = requests.post(REST_URL , files=files)
```

**Problem**:

I need to pass the additional information like this (All these are form parameters)

```
file (required) - sample file (multipart encoded file content)
package (optional) - analysis package to be used for the analysis
timeout (optional) (int) - analysis timeout (in seconds)
priority (optional) (int) - priority to assign to the task (1-3)
options (optional) - options to pass to the analysis package
machine (optional) - label of the analysis machine to use for the analysis
platform (optional) - name of the platform to select the analysis machine from (e.g. “windows”)
```

Suppose if i want to send machine name also in the form can i create like this ?

```
data = {'machine' :'machine_name'}
r =requests.post(EST_URL , files=files,data=data)
```

Any suggestions will help.

Comment: Yes ,  import requests

Comment: @das-g Type corrected

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Suppose if i want to send machine name also in the form can i create like this ?

---

> Request Quickstart [More complicated POST requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

If you want to test `requests` Parameter you can run the following:

```
import requests, io
url = 'http://httpbin.org/anything'

sample = io.StringIO('lorem ipsum')
files = {'file': ("temp_file_name", sample)}
data = {'machine': 'machine_name'}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)

r_dict = r.json()
for key in r_dict:
    print('{}:{}'.format(key, r_dict[key]))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> json:None
> headers:{'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '261', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.11.1', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=5ed95afb5ea2437eade92a826b29be0d', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*'}
> data:
> args:{}
> files:{'file': 'lorem ipsum'}
> method:POST
> url:http://httpbin.org/anything
> form:{'machine': 'machine_name'}
> ```

View http://httpbin.org, there are many other **url endpoints** you can test for.

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***